# AJAX success function not working when the page is load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

here is my code in ajax

```
function loadcountries()
              {
                var p = document.getElementById("selectCntry");

                while(p.firstChild)
                {
                  p.removeChild(p.firstChild);
                }
               var data = {
                        action: "loadccc"
                        };
                        jQuery.ajax
                        (
                          {
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajax-ows2.php",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            async:false,
                            data:data,
                            success: function(msg) 
                            {
                            alert(msg.test);                     
                            }
                          }
                        ); 

              }
```

here is my ajax-ows2.php

```
<?php


$action = $_POST["action"];

include "dbconnect.php";

if($action == "loadccc")
{
    $var = $action;
    $response_array['test'] = $var;

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response_array);
}

?>
```

and here is my function call:

```
 <script>

  window.onload = loadcountries;

  </script>
```

my ajax way is different. I really have no idea why it is not alerting when the page is load. Im really sure that my ajax-ows2.php is good and im sure that my function call is correct. Can somebody help me with this. This is not a duplicate one. I tried to used asynch:false but still not working.

Comment: data:data ? what data are you sending?

Comment: im sending all the data needed. look at my code var date {}

Comment: then update you code from var data to var date there is a typo :)

Comment: no that is a typo. in my code. var data is really the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

try this format:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    url: 'ajax-ows2.php',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);      
    },
    error: function (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

since you are doing POST method, your data parameter must be a stringify, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: how can I pass a action? where to put my action: "loadccc" ?

Comment: in "data" it must contain '{"action": "loadccc"}'